# java WeakReference. GC rarely occurs when the Old Generation area is full. (picture)

Tags: java, weak-references

The test was conducted using the WeakReference class. Look at the code.

```
public class ReferenceClassTest {
    private static List<WeakReference<BigData>> weakReferences = new LinkedList<>();
    private static List<SoftReference<BigData>> softReferences = new LinkedList<>();

    static class BigData {
        private int[] array = new int[2500];
    }

    public static void weakReferenceTest() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            while (true) {
                weakReferences.add(new WeakReference<>(new BigData()));
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.out.println("out of memory");
        }
    }

    public static void softReferenceTest() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            while (true) {
                softReferences.add(new SoftReference<>(new BigData()));
            }
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.out.println("out of memory");
        }
    }
}
```

And the picture is the GC result measured using the visualGC program.

> weakReferenceTest

[weakReferenceTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8rs0.png)

When you run "weakReferenceTest", heap memory usage continues to increase. Old Generation memory usage does not decrease when garbage collection occurs (Eventually, the Old Generation area fills up
). GC does not appear to occur even though the object is encapsulated with the WeakReference class.

> softReferenceTest

[softReferenceTest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6pSP.png)

This result looks very different from the result of running "softReferenceTest".

Why did this result happen?

Comment: The results look different because you are looking at two different tabs containing entirely different information. It’s not clear what conclusion you want to draw from that.

Answer (score 0):

While the `BigData` objects may not be strongly reachable, the `WeakReference` and `SoftReference` objects that point to them are reachable.   The `weakReferences` and `softReferences` collections are likely the source of the memory usage.

You can confirm by taking a heap dump (using tools like `jmap`) and viewing the heap usage using tools like [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/).